# How to import a Json arrays without overwriting existing objects in the FireBase RealTimeDB

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I import a large amount of JSON files to my FireBase DB console with this feature:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import

It works well when I upload arrays with lots of objects,
but if i want to upload a new array object to existing table, it overrides the existing object instead of adding the new one.

I would be happy to find a right way to "Update" the new objects to the existing table with firebase-import or any other tool.

Comment: Check out the Firebase CLI documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#database_commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Jen, you can use the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart#install-the-firebase-cli) to update objects in your database. Just use this command:

```
firebase database:update /path/to/object -d newArray.json
```

where:

- `/path/to/object` - the path of the object that you want to update.
- `newArray.json` - the json file containing the array with the new values.

Comment: I didn't even think of that. Great answer @JenPerson and Rosário!

Comment: The SLI works great but when i use this command:
 firebase:database:push /tradingDaysT date.json
its not create the correct child key order.

For example, in this https://imgbb.com/]https://image.ibb.co/dTTPZ6/ex.png
 it's creates this child name "--L39RnfnFR_bDDccsoLR" 
Instead of creating "1"
 thank you very much

Comment: What the push function does is create a unique key. And not increment the previous key. If you want to have incremented keys you should add the desired key to your json file and use `database:update` instead

Comment: Thank you , Is there any way to increment the key automatically ?
I mean, if in the database I have a keys of "0" , "1", "2".
The next key that will come up with the CLI will be "3"? It is not feasible to add a keys manually in a JSON files

Comment: Unfortunately, Firebase doesn't have a way to do that yet. You'd have to figure out a way for yourself.