# firebase database:update from CLI - multiple database in one project

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

My firebase project has multiple real-time databases (RTDB). How can I use the command line interface (CLI) to update a specific database when I have more than one?

```
$ firebase database:update --help

  Usage: database:update [options] <path> [infile]

  update some of the keys for the defined path in your Firebase

  Options:

    -d, --data <data>  specify escaped JSON directly
    -y, --confirm      pass this option to bypass confirmation prompt
    -h, --help         output usage information
```

I choose my project with `firebase use -add` but there is nothing in the help page about defining the URL to the database, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48311571/2327328). Both the node.js [firebase-import](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import) and the python [firebase-streaming-import](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-streaming-import) include the database URL as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that support for this was released today in [version 3.19.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v3.19.0).  `firebase database:get --help` now reports:

```
--instance <instance>    use the database <instance>.firebaseio.com (if omitted, use default database instance)
```

So, you should be able to use that to specify the shorthand instance name of your database.